# Swing GUI displays only artefacts on Java 8, Mac OS 10.7, Intel GMAX3100

Tags: java, macos, swing, osx-lion, java-8

When running a Java Swing application with java 8 on my mac with Mac OS X Lion (10.7) it often displays only random pixel/blocks from other parts of the screen. I'm using a Macbook Early 2008 (4,1) with a Intel GMA X3100. When I cause a repaint of the window (for example resizing the window) it displays correctly, but after some time it gets a mess again.

Anybody can help me? Is my system too old for Java 8? Or is it still a bug in Java 8? Running with jdk 6 it displays correctly.

Here is a sample picture of what it looks like:
[image]

Even Netbeans itself transform into something really crazy:
[image: Netbeans 8.0.1 running with jre 8 under Mac OS 10.7 on Macbook Early 2008]

Comment: Are these your programs that you're running? And if so, are you sure that they don't contain a bug?

Comment: The example above is an example GUI dialog from netbeans, it shouldn't contain any bugs ;) But my own applications are having these problems too (They work correctly under jdk 6)

Comment: I'm thinking that this may be a Java/video card issue.